# Bypass Two-Factor Authentication on iPhone

Tags: iphone, apple-id

My iPhone is stuck on the Apple screen, and everything I've found online says to connect it to iTunes to do a software update. I have connected it with my computer and performed a hard reset, and it now shows a different screen signaling me to connect to iTunes.

I can't log in to iTunes, however, because it requires 2FA, which is impossible because my iPhone isn't working in the first place.

Any workarounds?

Answer (score 2):

[Apple Support page on 2FA](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204915):

### What if I can't access a trusted device or didn't receive a verification code?

If you're signing in and don’t have a trusted device handy that can display verification codes, **you can have a code sent to your trusted phone number via text message or an automated phone call instead**.

Click "Didn't Get a Code" on the sign in screen and choose to send a code to your trusted phone number. You can also get a code directly from Settings on a trusted device.

There's more info on the "[Learn how to get a verification code](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204974)" page, too.